# Animating link border with CSS

Tags: css, border, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a blue border around a link that will animate and change the border color to yellow.

I have code that shows the hover animation but I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to add the blue outline of the plain link.

How can I create a blue outline that will transition into the yellow?

Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/Norm101/pen/QdvgaB

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0;
}
/*--------------------------------------------             
    
    ANIMATED LINKS
    ---------------------------------------------*/

div.al-hover {
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.al-hover a {
  font: arial;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-transition: ease-out 0.3s 0.1s;
  -o-transition: ease-out 0.3s 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition: ease-out 0.3s 0.1s;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
.al-hover a span::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #f5aa36;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.al-hover a span::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #f5aa36;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.al-hover a::before {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f5aa36;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.al-hover a::after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f5aa36;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.al-hover a:hover {
  color: #666;
}
.al-hover a:hover::before,
.al-hover a:hover::after {
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.al-hover a:hover span::before,
.al-hover a:hover span::after {
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="al-hover"><a href="/what-we-do/"><span>What We Do</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is one way to achieve the effect that you are looking for. The approach uses `linear-gradient` background for the four pseudo-elements that go towards creating the border like lines on the sides.

The approach works as follows:

- As mentioned above, all four pseudo-elements (which originally had a plain solid background) are assigned a `linear-gradient` which is blue colored for first 33%, smoothly transition from blue to yellow between 33% to 66% and then is yellow colored for the last 34% (that is from 66%).
- The `width` or the `height` of all the four pseudo-elements are set to `300%`. This makes sure that the blue color for 33% in the gradient actually means blue color for the entire width of the parent.
- These elements are originally translated in the X or Y axis (as required) by +/- `67%`. This means that only the blue colored part of the gradient is visible at the start.
- Once the hover is on, the pseudo-element traslations are nullified (or brought back to 0%). So the yellow colored portion of the gradient becomes visible at the end point. As the transition happens we also get to the see the in between portion (that is, the middle portion where the gradient goes from blue to yellow) and this makes it look as though the border color is smoothly going from blue to yellow like in a *side-to-side* color transition.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  Margin: 40px 0;
}
div.al-hover {
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.al-hover a {
  font: arial;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: ease-out 3s 0.1s;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
.al-hover a span::before {
  width: 300%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 3s;
  transform: translateX(-67%);
}
.al-hover a span::after {
  width: 300%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 3s;
  transform: translateX(67%);
}
.al-hover a::before {
  width: 1px;
  height: 300%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-67%);
  transition: 3s;
}
.al-hover a::after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 300%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(67%);
  transition: 3s;
}
.al-hover a:hover {
  color: #666;
}
.al-hover a:hover::before,
.al-hover a:hover::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.al-hover a:hover span::before,
.al-hover a:hover span::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="al-hover"><a href="/what-we-do/"><span>What We Do</span></a>
</div>
```

---

In the below snippet, I ***have removed the*** `overflow: hidden` in order for you to see how it is actually creating the effect.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  Margin: 40px 0;
}
div.al-hover {
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.al-hover a {
  font: arial;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: ease-out 3s 0.1s;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
.al-hover a span::before {
  width: 300%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 3s;
  transform: translateX(-67%);
}
.al-hover a span::after {
  width: 300%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 3s;
  transform: translateX(67%);
}
.al-hover a::before {
  width: 1px;
  height: 300%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-67%);
  transition: 3s;
}
.al-hover a::after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 300%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(67%);
  transition: 3s;
}
.al-hover a:hover {
  color: #666;
}
.al-hover a:hover::before,
.al-hover a:hover::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.al-hover a:hover span::before,
.al-hover a:hover span::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="al-hover"><a href="/what-we-do/"><span>What We Do</span></a>
</div>
```

---

The same effect can be achieved ***without using the 4 extra pseudo-elements*** also. This will involve using 4 background images and transitioning their `background-position` on hover.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  Margin: 40px 0;
}
div.al-hover {
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.al-hover a {
  font: arial;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: ease-out 3s 0.1s;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%), linear-gradient(to right, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%), linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%), linear-gradient(to top, blue 33%, #f5aa36 66%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 300% 1px, 300% 1px, 1px 300%, 1px 300%;
  background-position: right top, left bottom, right top, left bottom;
}
.al-hover a:hover {
  color: #666;
  background-position: left top, right bottom, right bottom, left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="al-hover"><a href="/what-we-do/">What We Do</a>
</div>
```

---

If ***that in-between transition effect is not required*** and just the blue needs to be replaced by yellow then we can do it like in the below snippet:

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  Margin: 40px 0;
}
div.al-hover {
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.al-hover a {
  font: arial;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: ease-out 3s 0.1s;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
.al-hover a span::before {
  width: 200%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue 50%, #f5aa36 50%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 3s;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.al-hover a span::after {
  width: 200%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 50%, #f5aa36 50%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 3s;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
.al-hover a::before {
  width: 1px;
  height: 200%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue 50%, #f5aa36 50%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 3s;
}
.al-hover a::after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 200%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 50%, #f5aa36 50%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  transition: 3s;
}
.al-hover a:hover {
  color: #666;
}
.al-hover a:hover::before,
.al-hover a:hover::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.al-hover a:hover span::before,
.al-hover a:hover span::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="al-hover"><a href="/what-we-do/"><span>What We Do</span></a>
</div>
```

---

This can also be ***improvised further*** to get something like the below where it looks like at the start of hover the blue is wiped out and then the yellow creeps in with the reverse happening on hover out.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  Margin: 40px 0;
}
div.al-hover {
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.al-hover a {
  font: arial;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: ease-out 3s 0.1s;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
.al-hover a span::before {
  width: 300%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue 33%, transparent 33%, transparent 66%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 3s;
  transform: translateX(-67%);
}
.al-hover a span::after {
  width: 300%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 33%, transparent 33%, transparent 66%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 3s;
  transform: translateX(67%);
}
.al-hover a::before {
  width: 1px;
  height: 300%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue 33%, transparent 33%, transparent 66%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-67%);
  transition: 3s;
}
.al-hover a::after {
  width: 1px;
  height: 300%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue 33%, transparent 33%, transparent 66%, #f5aa36 66%);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(67%);
  transition: 3s;
}
.al-hover a:hover {
  color: #666;
}
.al-hover a:hover::before,
.al-hover a:hover::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.al-hover a:hover span::before,
.al-hover a:hover span::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="al-hover"><a href="/what-we-do/"><span>What We Do</span></a>
</div>
```

(*Note: In all the snippets, I've increased the transition duration to make the transition more visible.*)

Comment: That was so much more thorough than I was expecting.  I'm going to study these to discover how they work.  Thank you so much!